# Import and Update Data From Excel to AWS SQL Server Using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I was trying to import multiple file from my local Excel files into SQL Server by using SSIS. I am able to successfully insert data into SQL Server.

However, what if I want to update a cell in Excel, how can I synchronize the changes from Excel to SQL Server by using SSIS.

Right now. What I can do is:

```
In Excel:

Col1   Col2
A       1
B       2
C       3
```

I can insert this from Excel to SQL Server.
However I change excel data into:

```
Col1   Col2
A       10
B       20
C       30
```

and insert it again, in SQL Server it will be:

```
Col1   Col2
A       1
B       2
C       3
A       10
B       20
C       30
```

If I want to keep the Excel and SQL Server exactly the same, what tools can I use in SSIS?

Other additional miscellaneous question:

1. It used to have something call "Refresh Microsoft Excel" in SSIS Toolbox, but I can't find it. What happens to that?
2. What if the Excel files is very large. Considering every time, drop table in SQL server, then execute an full insert from Excel won't be a great option.

Comment: 1. I've never heard of that. 2. No excel file is too big to drop and recreate in SQL Server. However this is the actual solution to your problem - truncate the table with a SQL Task then reload

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid 1. https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2015/01/ssis-excel-refresh-task/#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20Windows,authenticate%20to%20your%20data%20source.&text=In%20the%20Data%20tab%2C%20select,automatically%20by%20the%20refresh%20task.

Comment: Nice looks like you answered question 1 yourself

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually no. I was reading this article, and try to find the "Refresh Microsoft Excel" in my SSIS, but can't. Thats why I asked the first question.

Comment: You have to install it as per the installation instructions. If it has just disappeared out of the blue then you might find it is either not supported any more or your VS install is corrupted (both things happen regularly). Beware of using third party controls.

Comment: There is a comment in the tool telling that , it will only work in SSIS SQL Server 2012 edition. Read about it whether it supports higher versions

Comment: @VenkataramanR I dont think that function is supported anymore. I choose the 2 option, which drop the table first, then insert data again.